# Cakephp 2.X doesn't support postgresql ltree operator '?' likes "ltree ? lquery[]"

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, pdo

I use PostgreSQL `ltree` in a CakePHP 2.X controller and I found when I use the query like below:

```
$this->UserInfo->query(
    'select * from user_infos where path ? \'{'Test1.1','Test2.1'}\''
);
```

It can execute through the psql. The format due to **ltree ? lquery[]**

it will throw an error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7
ERROR: syntax error at or near "[" LINE 1:
       ...t * from user_infos where where path $1 \'{'Test1.1 ... ^
```

It seems the PDO treats **?** as **$1** argument?

Anyone has idea to prevent the problem?

Comment: More specifically, PDO (as many other database libraries) treats `?` as place-holder to be used in prepared statements. But finding `$1` being sent to server suggests that CakePHP is pre-processing the SQL code.

Comment: Normally CakePHP shouldn't touch raw queries. I would suspect this is about CakePHP 2.x, so the SQL should flow unchanged up to `PDO::prepare()`. What I would expect to see, despite a PHP parser error, would be an invalid parameter number error. Also where's that bracket? Are you sure that you are showing the code that you are actuall using?